# Webpage works in IE, Chrome and Firefox, but not when using the .NET WebBrowser control

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, webbrowser-control

I'm using the WebBrowser control in Visual Studio 2010 and trying to display the page: http://lk21.org.

Inside that webpage there are lots of scripts loaded, and it works fine if I open it through a web browser such as Firefox, Chrome, and the latest version of IE.

My question is, why does it display "Bad Request" when I tried using the WebBrowser component to navigate to that page?

Check this out:

[image]

---

**UPDATE:**

The page loads nicely using Visual Vincent's answer.

However the flash videos on the website (or I think it's something similar to flash) is unable to be played. See the comparison in the images below.

The strange thing is, if I open YouTube the flash works well. After a bit research, it seems to be caused by something else. Any clue how to solve it?

**Internet Explorer - works fine:**

[image]

**WebBrowser control - for some reason the video is stuck and can't be played:**

[image]

Comment: YouTube works fine because it is very optimized and doesn't always seem to use Flash (if I remember correctly I could still see YouTube videos before I installed Flash on my new computer). -- I will research the WebBrowser's issue with Flash, and hopefully return with a potential solution.

Comment: I have updated the answer and its code.

Comment: I have not been able to find anything more, so there isn't really much you can do right now other than switching browser. You could ask a new question about the flash problem (which you actually should have done in the first place) and see if anyone's able to answer it, but I wouldn't give it much hope. -- In the meantime I _recommend_ you to accept my answer since it did infact solve your initial problem.

Comment: I have edited your question to generalize the title and improve the overall readability. I did this is because I refer to my answer in here quite often to help others solve similar problems, but people are usually confused by the title and/or the questions contents, thinking that it is not related to their problem. Therefore I made the question a bit more general in order to (hopefully) minimize confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has probably got to do with that the `WebBrowser` control by default uses a document emulation mode of IE 7, meaning all pages are handled using the Internet Explorer 7 engine. Since that version is quite old most websites today are not compatible with it, which affects the functionality when you visit the page.

You can change this behaviour by adding a value for your application in the registry key `Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` in either the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` hive or `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`. By doing so you are forcing your application to use a **specific** version of the IE engine.

I've written a class which will help you with this:

```
'A class for changing the WebBrowser control's document emulation.
'Written by Visual Vincent, 2017.

Imports Microsoft.Win32
Imports System.Security
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public NotInheritable Class InternetExplorer
    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Const InternetExplorerRootKey As String = "Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer"
    Public Const BrowserEmulationKey As String = InternetExplorerRootKey & "\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION"
    Public Const ActiveXObjectCachingKey As String = InternetExplorerRootKey & "\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_OBJECT_CACHING"

    Private Shared ReadOnly WebBrowserInstance As New WebBrowser 'Used to get the current IE version in a .NET-friendly manner.

    Public Enum BrowserEmulation As Integer
        IE7 = 7000
        IE8 = 8000
        IE8Standards = 8888
        IE9 = 9000
        IE9Standards = 9999
        IE10 = 10000
        IE10Standards = 10001
        IE11 = 11000
        IE11Edge = 11001
    End Enum

    Public Shared Sub SetLatestBrowserEmulation(ByVal Root As RegistryRoot)
        Dim Emulation As BrowserEmulation = BrowserEmulation.IE7
        Select Case WebBrowserInstance.Version.Major
            Case Is >= 11 : Emulation = BrowserEmulation.IE11Edge
            Case 10 : Emulation = BrowserEmulation.IE10Standards
            Case 9 : Emulation = BrowserEmulation.IE9Standards
            Case 8 : Emulation = BrowserEmulation.IE8Standards
        End Select
        InternetExplorer.SetBrowserEmulation(Root, Emulation)
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub SetBrowserEmulation(ByVal Root As RegistryRoot, ByVal Emulation As BrowserEmulation)
        Using RootKey As RegistryKey = Root.Root
            Dim EmulationKey As RegistryKey = RootKey.OpenSubKey(BrowserEmulationKey, True)
            If EmulationKey Is Nothing Then EmulationKey = RootKey.CreateSubKey(BrowserEmulationKey, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree)

            Using EmulationKey
                EmulationKey.SetValue(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName & ".exe", CType(Emulation, Integer), RegistryValueKind.DWord)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub SetActiveXObjectCaching(ByVal Root As RegistryRoot, ByVal Enabled As Boolean)
        Using RootKey As RegistryKey = Root.Root
            Dim ObjectCachingKey As RegistryKey = RootKey.OpenSubKey(ActiveXObjectCachingKey, True)
            If ObjectCachingKey Is Nothing Then ObjectCachingKey = RootKey.CreateSubKey(ActiveXObjectCachingKey, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree)

            Using ObjectCachingKey
                ObjectCachingKey.SetValue(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName & ".exe", CType(If(Enabled, 1, 0), Integer), RegistryValueKind.DWord)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub

    Public NotInheritable Class RegistryRoot
        Private _root As RegistryKey

        Public ReadOnly Property Root As RegistryKey
            Get
                Return _root
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Shared ReadOnly Property HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE As RegistryRoot
            Get
                Return New RegistryRoot(Registry.LocalMachine)
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Shared ReadOnly Property HKEY_CURRENT_USER As RegistryRoot
            Get
                Return New RegistryRoot(Registry.CurrentUser)
            End Get
        End Property

        Private Sub New(ByVal Root As RegistryKey)
            Me._root = Root
        End Sub
    End Class
End Class
```

To use it, put **one** of these lines in the application's `Startup` event:

```
InternetExplorer.SetLatestBrowserEmulation(InternetExplorer.RegistryRoot.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)

'HKEY_CURRENT_USER is recommended if you do not want to run your application with administrative privileges.
InternetExplorer.SetLatestBrowserEmulation(InternetExplorer.RegistryRoot.HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
```

(**NOTE:** Using the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` root requires administrative privileges)

The `InternetExplorer.SetLatestBrowserEmulation()` method will set the browser emulation for your application, in the specified registry root, to the **latest INSTALLED version** of Internet Explorer.

However using the `InternetExplorer.SetBrowserEmulation()` method you can manually control what IE version it should use ***(not recommended!)***.

**Read more:**

- [**Internet Feature Controls - Browser emulation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx#browser_emulation)
- [**`Application.Startup` event**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.startup(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [**How to: Handle Application Events (Visual Basic)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2bys999(v=vs.100).aspx)

---

### EDIT

I seem to be unable to enter that site at all, but from what I've read [**there have been problems with Flash hosted in the WebBrowser control**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johan/2009/08/06/problems-with-flash-content-in-the-webbrowser-control/).

What you can try is to disable the [**ActiveX Object Caching feature**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330729(v=vs.85).aspx#object_caching), which can apparently cause some issues for Flash controls.

I updated the above `InternetExplorer` class. Copy-paste it, then add this line to your application's startup event:

```
InternetExplorer.SetActiveXObjectCaching(InternetExplorer.RegistryRoot.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, False)
```

If it still doesn't work then I'm afraid you're out of luck. I have not been able to find anything else that is useful.

Comment: thanks @VisualVincent,... but that doesnt mean i have to install the new browser version into my computer isn't? Just editing the registry and run again the project is enough, isn't? :D

Comment: @gumuruh : You do not have to install anything, no. This code will automatically use the version of IE that is **currently installed on your computer**.

Comment: @gumuruh : You don't even need to close your project for this to work. Just include my code and put `InternetExplorer.SetLatestBrowserEmulation(InternetExplorer.RegistryRoot.HKEY_CURRENT_USER)` in the application's `Startup` event and everything will be taken care of automatically.

Comment: i mean i can use IEv11 feature on the WebBrowser component without even have the app installed first? @VisualVincent....

Comment: @gumuruh : No, of course not. It must be installed in the system. How should your application use IE 11 if not even the operating system knows it exists? :)

Comment: @gumuruh : Windows 7 comes pre-installed with IE 8. At that time IE 11 didn't exist (of course), so if the user hasn't installed the latest via Windows Update or otherwise, then the OS is not aware of its existance.

Comment: oh, hehe... okay for that. What about the Application startup event,...? I have written it, but there's an error said "Declaration Expected" on the Internetexplorer code you just posted above....

Comment: @gumuruh : Could you update the question and show the event handler? Include a screenshot as well, if possible.

Comment: @gumuruh : You never declared the event handler. Open the drop down for the combo box that currently says `MyApplication` and select `(MyApplication events)`. Then open the drop down for the combo box that says `Declarations` and select `Startup`. Now put the code in the newly created event handler.

Comment: okay,... I got it. But some problems still there. Check out the updated details i wrote above.

Comment: ,... caching? that only for ie8 case if i'm not mistaken. cmiiw. anyway, If you want to access it the web,... you could visit using proxy surfing... or somewhere similar to hideass web. let me know if u're success or something. :D

Comment: @gumuruh : I'm afraid you are mistaken. It is **enabled by default** for IE 8 **and above**. It's _**NOT only**_ for IE 8. Anyway, as I said it's a known problem that flash doesn't always function correctly in the WebBrowser control. There isn't much you can do other than to try another web browser, such as [**GeckoFX**](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/).

Comment: I have already checked what you wrote above and disabling caching was the potential fix... But since it didn't work there isn't much you can do other than to switch browser.

Comment: you're right. I now use GeckoFX, and the all problems such as flash video streaming, etc are all solved! :D

Comment: The WebBrowser.Version property always returns the latest installed version of IE, not the version associated to the browser emulation version specified. Also the solution is not x86/x64 registry view aware.

Comment: @ElektroStudios : I am only using `WebBrowser.Version` to get the _**latest installed version**_, so there's no problem with that :). And actually, the solution _**is**_ already x86/x64 aware. Windows automatically redirects x86 apps to the `Wow6432Node`, and lets x64 apps access the normal registry, so there is no need to change anything (**I have tested and verified this as well**, it works just the way it should). It is actually the _other_ solutions out there that are doing it wrong. In cases like this there's no need to take the x86/x64 view into account. Windows does all that for you.

Comment: @ElektroStudios : For reference: [_**Registry Redirector (Windows) - MSDN**_](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Based on @**Visual Vincent** answer, here I did a reworked solution:

1 - **IEBrowserEmulationMode** enumeration:

```
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <summary>
''' Specifies a Internet Explorer browser emulation mode.
''' </summary>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <remarks>
''' <see href="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/general-info/ee330730(v=vs.85)"/>
''' </remarks>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Enum IEBrowserEmulationMode As Integer

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE7 Standards mode.
    ''' </summary>
    IE7 = 7000

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE8 mode. 
    ''' </summary>
    IE8 = 8000

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Webpages are displayed in IE8 Standards mode, regardless of the declared !DOCTYPE directive. 
    ''' <para></para>
    ''' Failing to declare a !DOCTYPE directive causes the page to load in Quirks.
    ''' </summary>
    IE8Standards = 8888

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE9 mode.
    ''' </summary>
    IE9 = 9000

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Webpages are displayed in IE9 Standards mode, regardless of the declared !DOCTYPE directive. 
    ''' <para></para>
    ''' Failing to declare a !DOCTYPE directive causes the page to load in Quirks.
    ''' </summary>
    IE9Standards = 9999

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE10 Standards mode.
    ''' </summary>
    IE10 = 10000

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Webpages are displayed in IE10 Standards mode, regardless of the !DOCTYPE directive.
    ''' </summary>
    IE10Standards = 10001

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE11 edge mode.
    ''' </summary>
    IE11 = 11000

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Webpages are displayed in IE11 edge mode, regardless of the declared !DOCTYPE directive. 
    ''' <para></para>
    ''' Failing to declare a !DOCTYPE directive causes the page to load in Quirks.
    ''' </summary>
    IE11Edge = 11001

End Enum
```

2 - **RegistryScope** enumeration.

```
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <summary>
''' Specifies a registry scope (a root key).
''' </summary>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Enum RegistryScope As Integer

    ''' <summary>
    ''' This refers to the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE (or HKLM) registry root key.
    ''' <para></para>
    ''' Configuration changes made on the subkeys of this root key will affect all users.
    ''' </summary>
    Machine = 0

    ''' <summary>
    ''' This refers to the HKEY_CURRENT_USER (or HKCU) registry root key.
    ''' <para></para>
    ''' Configuration changes made on the subkeys of this root key will affect only the current user.
    ''' </summary>
    CurrentUser = 1

End Enum
```

3 - **BrowserEmulationMode** property, to get or set the IE Browser Emulation mode for the current application.

```
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <summary>
''' Gets or sets the Internet Explorer browser emulation mode for the current application.
''' </summary>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <seealso href="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/general-info/ee330730(v=vs.85)"/>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <example> This is a code example to get, set and verify the IE browser emulation mode for the current process.
''' <code>
''' Dim scope As RegistryScope = RegistryScope.CurrentUser
''' Dim oldMode As IEBrowserEmulationMode
''' Dim newMode As IEBrowserEmulationMode
''' 
''' oldMode = BrowserEmulationMode(scope)
''' BrowserEmulationMode(scope) = IEBrowserEmulationMode.IE11Edge
''' newMode = BrowserEmulationMode(scope)
''' 
''' Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Old Mode: {0} ({1})", oldMode, CStr(oldMode)))
''' Console.WriteLine(String.Format("New Mode: {0} ({1})", newMode, CStr(newMode)))
''' 
''' Dim f As New Form() With {.Size = New Size(1280, 720)}
''' Dim wb As New WebBrowser With {.Dock = DockStyle.Fill}
''' f.Controls.Add(wb)
''' f.Show()
''' wb.Navigate("http://www.whatversion.net/browser/")
''' </code>
''' </example>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <param name="scope">
''' The registry scope.
''' </param>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <value>
''' The Internet Explorer browser emulation mode.
''' </value>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Shared Property BrowserEmulationMode(ByVal scope As RegistryScope) As IEBrowserEmulationMode
    <DebuggerStepThrough>
    Get
        Return GetIEBrowserEmulationMode(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName, scope)
    End Get
    <DebuggerStepThrough>
    Set(value As IEBrowserEmulationMode)
        SetIEBrowserEmulationMode(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName, scope, value)
    End Set
End Property
```

3 - **GetIEBrowserEmulationMode** function and **SetIEBrowserEmulationMode** method, to get or set the IE Browser Emulation mode for a external application.

```
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <summary>
''' Gets the Internet Explorer browser emulation mode for the specified process.
''' </summary>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <seealso href="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/general-info/ee330730(v=vs.85)"/>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <example> This is a code example.
''' <code>
''' Dim processName As String = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName
''' Dim scope As RegistryScope = RegistryScope.CurrentUser
''' Dim mode As IEBrowserEmulationMode = GetIEBrowserEmulationMode(processName, scope)
''' 
''' Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Mode: {0} ({1})", mode, CStr(mode)))
''' </code>
''' </example>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <param name="processName">
''' The process name (eg. 'cmd.exe').
''' </param>
''' 
''' <param name="scope">
''' The registry scope.
''' </param>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <returns>
''' The resulting <see cref="IEBrowserEmulationMode"/>.
''' </returns>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <exception cref="NotSupportedException">
''' </exception>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<DebuggerStepThrough>
Public Shared Function GetIEBrowserEmulationMode(ByVal processName As String, ByVal scope As RegistryScope) As IEBrowserEmulationMode

    processName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(processName)

    Using rootKey As RegistryKey = If(scope = RegistryScope.CurrentUser,
                                      RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryView.Default),
                                      RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Default)),
          subKey As RegistryKey = rootKey.CreateSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION",
                                                       RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree)

        Dim value As Integer =
            CInt(subKey.GetValue(String.Format("{0}.exe", processName), 0, RegistryValueOptions.None))

        ' If no browser emulation mode is retrieved from registry, then return default version for WebBrowser control.
        If (value = 0) Then
            Return IEBrowserEmulationMode.IE7
        End If

        If [Enum].IsDefined(GetType(IEBrowserEmulationMode), value) Then
            Return DirectCast(value, IEBrowserEmulationMode)

        Else
            Throw New NotSupportedException(String.Format("Undefined browser emulation value retrieved from registry: '{0}'", value))


        End If

    End Using

End Function

''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <summary>
''' Gets the Internet Explorer browser emulation mode for the specified process.
''' </summary>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <seealso href="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/general-info/ee330730(v=vs.85)"/>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <example> This is a code example.
''' <code>
''' Dim p As Process = Process.GetCurrentProcess()
''' Dim scope As RegistryScope = RegistryScope.CurrentUser
''' Dim mode As IEBrowserEmulationMode = GetIEBrowserEmulationMode(p, scope)
''' 
''' Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Mode: {0} ({1})", mode, CStr(mode)))
''' </code>
''' </example>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <param name="p">
''' The process.
''' </param>
''' 
''' <param name="scope">
''' The registry scope.
''' </param>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <returns>
''' The resulting <see cref="IEBrowserEmulationMode"/>.
''' </returns>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <exception cref="NotSupportedException">
''' </exception>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<DebuggerStepThrough>
Public Shared Function GetIEBrowserEmulationMode(ByVal p As Process, ByVal scope As RegistryScope) As IEBrowserEmulationMode

    Return GetIEBrowserEmulationMode(p.ProcessName, scope)

End Function

''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <summary>
''' Sets the Internet Explorer browser emulation mode for the specified process.
''' </summary>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <seealso href="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/general-info/ee330730(v=vs.85)"/>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <example> This is a code example.
''' <code>
''' Dim processName As String = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName
''' Dim scope As RegistryScope = RegistryScope.CurrentUser
''' Dim oldMode As IEBrowserEmulationMode
''' Dim newMode As IEBrowserEmulationMode
''' 
''' oldMode = GetIEBrowserEmulationMode(processName, scope)
''' SetIEBrowserEmulationMode(processName, scope, IEBrowserEmulationMode.IE11Edge)
''' newMode = GetIEBrowserEmulationMode(processName, scope)
''' 
''' Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Old Mode: {0} ({1})", oldMode, CStr(oldMode)))
''' Console.WriteLine(String.Format("New Mode: {0} ({1})", newMode, CStr(newMode)))
''' 
''' Dim f As New Form() With {.Size = New Size(1280, 720)}
''' Dim wb As New WebBrowser With {.Dock = DockStyle.Fill}
''' f.Controls.Add(wb)
''' f.Show()
''' wb.Navigate("http://www.whatversion.net/browser/")
''' </code>
''' </example>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <param name="processName">
''' The process name (eg. 'cmd.exe').
''' </param>
''' 
''' <param name="scope">
''' The registry scope.
''' </param>
''' 
''' <param name="mode">
''' The Internet Explorer browser emulation mode to set.
''' </param>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <exception cref="NotSupportedException">
''' </exception>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<DebuggerStepThrough>
Public Shared Sub SetIEBrowserEmulationMode(ByVal processName As String, ByVal scope As RegistryScope, ByVal mode As IEBrowserEmulationMode)

    processName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(processName)

    Dim currentIEBrowserEmulationMode As IEBrowserEmulationMode = GetIEBrowserEmulationMode(processName, scope)
    If (currentIEBrowserEmulationMode = mode) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Using rootKey As RegistryKey = If(scope = RegistryScope.CurrentUser,
                                      RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryView.Default),
                                      RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Default)),
          subKey As RegistryKey = rootKey.CreateSubKey(
                    "Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION",
                    RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree)

        subKey.SetValue(String.Format("{0}.exe", processName),
                        DirectCast(mode, Integer), RegistryValueKind.DWord)

    End Using

End Sub

''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <summary>
''' Sets the Internet Explorer browser emulation mode for the specified process.
''' </summary>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <seealso href="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/general-info/ee330730(v=vs.85)"/>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <example> This is a code example.
''' <code>
''' Dim processName As Process = Process.GetCurrentProcess()
''' Dim scope As RegistryScope = RegistryScope.CurrentUser
''' Dim oldMode As IEBrowserEmulationMode
''' Dim newMode As IEBrowserEmulationMode
''' 
''' oldMode = GetIEBrowserEmulationMode(p, scope)
''' SetIEBrowserEmulationMode(p, scope, IEBrowserEmulationMode.IE11Edge)
''' newMode = GetIEBrowserEmulationMode(p, scope)
''' 
''' Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Old Mode: {0} ({1})", oldMode, CStr(oldMode)))
''' Console.WriteLine(String.Format("New Mode: {0} ({1})", newMode, CStr(newMode)))
''' 
''' Dim f As New Form() With {.Size = New Size(1280, 720)}
''' Dim wb As New WebBrowser With {.Dock = DockStyle.Fill}
''' f.Controls.Add(wb)
''' f.Show()
''' wb.Navigate("http://www.whatversion.net/browser/")
''' </code>
''' </example>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <param name="p">
''' The process.
''' </param>
''' 
''' <param name="scope">
''' The registry scope.
''' </param>
''' 
''' <param name="mode">
''' The Internet Explorer browser emulation mode to set.
''' </param>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <exception cref="NotSupportedException">
''' </exception>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<DebuggerStepThrough>
Public Shared Sub SetIEBrowserEmulationMode(ByVal p As Process, ByVal scope As RegistryScope, ByVal mode As IEBrowserEmulationMode)

    SetIEBrowserEmulationMode(p.ProcessName, scope, mode)

End Sub
```

---

Usage example to get, set and verify the IE browser emulation mode for the current process:

```
Dim scope As RegistryScope = RegistryScope.CurrentUser
Dim oldMode As IEBrowserEmulationMode
Dim newMode As IEBrowserEmulationMode

oldMode = BrowserEmulationMode(scope)
BrowserEmulationMode(scope) = IEBrowserEmulationMode.IE11Edge
newMode = BrowserEmulationMode(scope)

Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Old Mode: {0} ({1})", oldMode, CStr(oldMode)))
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("New Mode: {0} ({1})", newMode, CStr(newMode)))

Dim f As New Form() With {.Size = New Size(1280, 720)}
Dim wb As New WebBrowser With {.Dock = DockStyle.Fill}
f.Controls.Add(wb)
f.Show()
wb.Navigate("http://www.whatversion.net/browser/")
```

Usage example to get, set and verify the IE browser emulation mode for a specific process:

```
Dim processName As String = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName
Dim scope As RegistryScope = RegistryScope.CurrentUser
Dim oldMode As IEBrowserEmulationMode
Dim newMode As IEBrowserEmulationMode

oldMode = GetIEBrowserEmulationMode(processName, scope)
SetIEBrowserEmulationMode(processName, scope, IEBrowserEmulationMode.IE11Edge)
newMode = GetIEBrowserEmulationMode(processName, scope)

Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Old Mode: {0} ({1})", oldMode, CStr(oldMode)))
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("New Mode: {0} ({1})", newMode, CStr(newMode)))

Dim f As New Form() With {.Size = New Size(1280, 720)}
Dim wb As New WebBrowser With {.Dock = DockStyle.Fill}
f.Controls.Add(wb)
f.Show()
wb.Navigate("http://www.whatversion.net/browser/")
```

Comment: Hadn't noticed this until now... Nice code, though apart from that mine cannot _get_ the current version I don't see why you felt it necessary to do a remake? (Ok, the `RegistryRoot` class is perhaps not very efficient, and I actually have no idea why I created it, but still ;)

Comment: @Visual Vincent, thanks for comment. I just discovered and liked your idea and your solution, then I wanted to implement this kind of feature into one library of mine,but I don't like just to copy&paste other codes without understand what the code really does, so I needed to rewrite/refactor it from scratch (and investigate official sources to add the XML documentation to) your original code to appear a little bit more reusable/friendly usage for general needs (adding the members I added,renaming methods,and removing what I considered unnecessary members),then finally I just shared what I did.

Comment: OMG. Why does this have to be so complicated.