# The WebBrowser control does not support the RightToLeft property VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Is there any way to display content in webbrowser RightToLeft  in VB.NET ?
I'm using VB 2015

Comment: It is up to the website to display the content as RTL, not the `WebBrowser` control. So without modifying the page the answer is: **No**.

Comment: the website is an Arabic website 
so all page is  RTL

Comment: If the website _is_ RTL then the `WebBrowser` should display it as such as well. Try changing the browser's [**document emulation**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42365833/vb-net-visual-studio-web-browser-navigate-bad-request/42367088#42367088).