# GetAttribute don't work with "html string format attribute" from webbrowser.document

Tags: html, vb.net

In the following html document :

```html
<div id="main">
  <a class="class1">text</a>
  <div href="domain.com">text</div>
</div>
```

I try to get the InnerTxt :

```
   For Each elem As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("main").Children

        If elem.GetAttribute("className").Equals("class1") Then
            TextBox1.Text = elem.InnerText
        End If

    Next
```

I somehow found that I needed to search "className" instead of "class", but I don't find any correspondence for "href".

I used to work with SHDocVw before, and .getAttribute("class") or any attribute worked perfectly. However it was .getAttribute (starting with lowsercase and not .GetAttribute starting with uppercase)

Is there a way to get attribute with "class" instead of "className" (and so on for any attribute type)?

Comment: `class` vs `className` isn't related to your issue. Checking for `class` instead won't work and you are right that you should be using `className`.

Comment: Running your **exact** code on that **exact** HTML snippet works. Did you try it yourself in a new project? -- Could you please show us some more code - for instance _**where**_ this code of yours is run? And if possible also a little piece of the real HTML code (since I assume this is dummy code).

Comment: Instead of `GetElementById("main").Children` you could also try `GetElementById("main").All` and see how that works for you.

Comment: @Visualvincent Thanks for your response, I haven't tried this exact HTML snippet, I tried .All instead of .Children without success. I'm out for today, I'll try more tomorrow if I have the time to work on this. Last thing I forget to mention is I changed default VS2017 Webbrowser UserAgent to "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko" (IE11)

Comment: Why not change the browser emulation instead to make your `WebBrowser` actually use IE11: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42367088/3740093 (ignore the edit)