# How to press a button in vb.net web-browser

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net, web, element

Hello I'm working on a easy account menu for signing into steam via web-browser. I'm trying to make a button auto sign in the person. I'm able to have the button auto fill the password and the username, but the submit button will not work.

Here is the link to steam's login: [Here](https://steamcommunity.com/login/home/?goto=)

Here is the element view of the button. Also note that it looks like it branches to maybe some kind of event?
[image]

I'm kind of stumped on how to approch this. Is there a way I can use web-console to submit it that way? Here is what I got so far:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    WebBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True

    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("input_username").SetAttribute("value", TextBox1.Text)

    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("input_password").SetAttribute("value", TextBox2.Text)

    WebBrowser1.Document.All("login_btn_signin").InvokeMember("click")

End Sub
```

Comment: The `WebBrowser` control by default uses a document emulation mode of Internet Explorer 7, which I doubt Steam's website is compatible with today. Your code should work, but it probably doesn't because there are (script) errors due to that the browser version is too old. Switching to the latest installed IE version on the system (which hopefully is IE 11/Edge) will most likely solve the problem. See my answer here: [Vb.net Visual Studio Web Browser Navigate Bad Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42365833/vb-net-visual-studio-web-browser-navigate-bad-request)

Comment: The browser does pull up steams website just fine and I'm able to manually sign in. The code also inputs the the username and password. I don't see why needing to use a higher browser is needed but I can try.

Comment: Though by setting `WebBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True` you never truly know if there is any script error(s) or not. Though you should still switch to the latest version since IE 7 is _**really**_ old, making the probability of something failing _**very high**_.

Comment: I just noticed the actual problem... I should've examined your image more thoroughly ;). See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After examining your image properly I noticed the you are clicking the wrong element. That `<div id="login_btn_signin">` element is just a container and doesn't do anything. You should be clicking the underlying `<button>` element.

Since the button itself doesn't have an ID you'll have to use a workaround:

```
'Get the "login_btn_signin" parent/container div.
Dim LoginButtonContainer As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login_btn_signin")

'Get the first found <button> element in the container div.
Dim LoginButton As HtmlElement = LoginButtonContainer.GetElementsByTagName("button")(0)

'Click the button.
LoginButton.InvokeMember("click")
```

Comment: @JohnKens : Glad I could help!