# VB.NET webbrowser click button

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I know this question has been asked many times and I have tried quite a few and none work.

I have a `WebBrowser` and 1 button. When I click the form button it needs to invoke a click on the `WebBrowser` button.

I have tried

```
WebBrowser1.Document.All("start-button").InvokeMember("click")
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("convert1").InvokeMember("Click")

For Each element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
    If element.GetAttribute("id") = "convert1" Then
        element.InvokeMember("click")
    End If
Next
```

None of the above works.

[Link to website](https://www.onlinevideoconverter.com/video-converter)

Code from the webpage source

```
<a class="start-button" href="javascript:;" id="convert1" onmouseover="changeImage(this, '');" onmouseout="changeImage(this, '');">
    Start
    <i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-5"></i>
</a>
```

Also the button on the `WebBrowser`, when I click it nothing happens for some reason.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webpage works in IE, Chrome and Firefox, but not when using the .NET WebBrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42365833/webpage-works-in-ie-chrome-and-firefox-but-not-when-using-the-net-webbrowser)

Comment: How is this a duplicate ? Its completely different.

Comment: As a matter of fact it isn't that different. You stated that the button doesn't work when you click it; that's actually related to the question's title and implicitly also the question, because the _**underlying problem**_ is the same). However most importantly it is related to _**my answer**_.

Comment: What you are experiencing is a result of the `WebBrowser` control using the IE 7 engine rather than IE 11/Edge, which is explained in my answer to that question. If you implement it I can _**almost certainly**_ guarantee that your code (and the button on the website) will work. :) -- If that isn't the case however I will check it out more thoroughly. Be sure to test it more than one time though, as it doesn't always work on the first run.