# Click <Tr> Tag Automaticly

Tags: html, vb.net, click, mshtml

```
<tr class="rowClass1" id="TR_parentof_form1:tableExIlacList:0:rowAction1" onclick="return(hX_6.runEvent(this, event));" style="cursor: pointer;"><td><span id="form1:tableExIlacList:0:rowAction1">
```

These are the HTML codes which I want to click it automatically.

Here is my codes:

```
Dim f As HtmlElement
        f = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("TR_parentof_form1:tableExIlacList:0:rowAction1")
        f.InvokeMember("click")
```

It is not working. I still dont know why my code does not invoke the click command.

Comment: There are more codes under <Tr> tags : `<input type="hidden" id="form1:tableExIlacList:0:rowAction1__hidden_action" name="form1:tableExIlacList:0:rowAction1__hidden_action" value="false" disabled="disabled">` I tried to invoke them but it is not working too.

Comment: The `WebBrowser` control by default uses the Internet Explorer 7 engine, which is too old to handle most of today's websites. You're most likely getting a script error from that code of yours, but it isn't shown if you've set the `ScriptErrorsSuppressed` property to `True`. You can try forcing it to use the latest installed version of IE, which should fix the problem if I'm correct. See this answer of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42367088/3740093

Comment: I am looking at your link now. Thanks.

Comment: I think i have to remove "disabled" attribute and make "value=true"

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

```
  f.SetAttribute("disabled", "")
            f.SetAttribute("type", "submit")
            f.SetAttribute("value", "true")
            f.OuterHtml.Replace("disabled", "")
            f.InvokeMember("click")
```