# WebBroswer Component not working the same a regular browser

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In VB.NET the WebBrowser component won't work the same as the actual browser [IE or Chrome] for the window.onbeforeunload event.

In the **browser** the event only runs when the page is going to post by a button push. But for the link to fire the javaScript function that opens a new window the event is not triggered.

In the **VB.Net application with the WebBrowser** component, the javaScript causes the event to trigger. This java code is called through a href link tag.

The buttons are **ASP:Button** for which I need the button.OnClick event to work in the coding page.

The disable button function works fine....

I already have this meta tag in 
"`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`"

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
function popupWindow(url, windowName) {
    myWindow = window.open(url, windowName, "toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=750, height=500, left=10, top=10");
}

function disableButton(element) {
    if (!element) { return; }
    element.disabled = true;
    var disp = element.style.display;
    element.style.display = 'none';
    var trick = element.offsetHeight;
    element.style.display = disp;
}


function disableButtons() {
    disableButton(document.getElementById('<% =Button1.ClientID %>'))
    disableButton(document.getElementById('<% =Button2.ClientID %>'))
    disableButton(document.getElementById('<% =Button3.ClientID %>'))
}

window.onbeforeunload = disableButtons;
```

```
<html portion>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" /><br /><br />
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" /><br /><br />
<asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Button" /><br /><br />

<a href="javascript:popupWindow('ProjLocation.aspx','ProjLocation')">ProjLocation</a><br /><br />
```

Comment: The control defaults to an older version of IE, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922308/use-latest-version-of-internet-explorer-in-the-webbrowser-control - Perhaps that's the issue.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Tried <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> and <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11" />. My machine and the client machines all have IE 11. That been said I still don't know the version running when using the WebBrowser component.

Comment: Open http://www.thismachine.info/ in the component & it will tell you the version, if its not what you expect use the code in the linked answer to bump it up to 11.

Comment: Alex, It show IE7 how would I force it to use IE 11?

Comment: Use the registry tweaks in the linked answer.

Comment: VB.NET version of Alex K.'s suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42367088

Comment: Thanks. Went back to the previous stackoverflow page suggested which led me to this: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730(VS.85).aspx#browser_emulation) which showed me how to make a registry adjustment for the running application. The version is now defined correctly but the javascript still isn't working. @Alex

Comment: Have you set the registry value to `11001` and do you also have IE 11 or Edge installed on the computer?

Comment: The about says IE 11. here is the copy from ThisMachine.info
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko