# VB.Net Webbrowser Inspect Element

Tags: vb.net, element, inspect

I've been trying to figure out the ID of a button on a webpage in the VB webbrowser, but as VB uses an outdated web browser so the webpage loads differently to chrome so I can't figure out what the ID of the button is.

Is there any way I can get the ID of a focused element with some code?

Or alternatively, what web browser does VB use, so I can do figure it out manually.

Thanks!

Comment: It uses IE under the covers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser?view=netframework-4.7.1

Comment: .NET uses an embedded version of Internet Explorer, with a document emulation of IE 7. If you want to change that to the latest installed version of IE refer to my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42367088

Comment: Thanks! Was able to figure it out using the developer tools with IE.