# How to click Image button in website vb.net

Tags: vb.net

so i am trying to click a image button in website with HTML code:

```
<a onclick="trylogin()"><img class="loginButton" src="/student/resource/AWSEd_Resource/img/search-execute.png"></a>
```

i've tried:

```
Dim element As HtmlElement = (From el As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a").Cast(Of HtmlElement).Where(Function(h) h.GetAttribute("onclick") = "trylogin()")).FirstOrDefault()
        element.InvokeMember("click")
```

And:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.Forms(0).InvokeMember("loginButton")
```

[This is image button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMj2k.jpg)

Comment: Please show us the HTML code for the `<a>` element.

Comment: <a onclick="trylogin()"><img class="loginButton" src="/student/resource/AWSEd_Resource/img/search-execute.png"></a>

Comment: If nothing works your issue is likely caused by the fact that the `WebBrowser` control is using the IE 7 engine. See my answer here: Possible duplicate of [Webpage works in IE, Chrome and Firefox, but not when using the .NET WebBrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42365833/webpage-works-in-ie-chrome-and-firefox-but-not-when-using-the-net-webbrowser)

Answer (score 0):

Try executing the script directly using [**`HtmlDocument.InvokeScript()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/be9zzz62(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("trylogin")
```

Comment: dont work nothing happens. just to let you know that the picture button is not even responsive in webbrowser window when i click it in web browser nothing happens too, but button works fine in chrome and firefox

Comment: @RanaJawad are you making sure the document is fully loaded before trying to invoke scripts?

Comment: @Jaxi i am using WaitForPageLoad() before this

Comment: @RanaJawad : Nonono, don't do that! That function is bad and you ought get rid of it right now! The [**`DocumentCompleted` event**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) is the only good thing you can use to wait for the page to load completely.

Comment: @RanaJawad : As I said in the comment on your question: Try out my answer given to the following post, it should solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42365833/webpage-works-in-ie-chrome-and-firefox-but-not-when-using-the-net-webbrowser