# Fix WebBrowser Control When Load Javascript Code?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, webbrowser-control

This question is so important for me and other students.
How we can make the `WebBrowser` control, in `VB.Net` or `C#`, load `JavaScript` without any error?
I need to make the program load the page correctly without make the page destroyed, sometimes its matter too much if there no `JavaScript`.
I tried this solution: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r-j_tgbsp7g but no luck.

This is a picture for the problem:

[image]

So anybody can help us (because a lot of people have this problem).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webpage works in IE, Chrome and Firefox, but not when using the .NET WebBrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42365833/webpage-works-in-ie-chrome-and-firefox-but-not-when-using-the-net-webbrowser)

Comment: For the record, your question gets Very Hard To Read If You Capitalize The First Character Of Every Word

Comment: In addition to the duplicate above, you can set the [**`WebBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed` property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.scripterrorssuppressed(v=vs.110).aspx) to True to prevent script errors _from being shown_ (they're still there though).

Comment: The script is broke, the ones that can fix it is the people responsible for maintaining the site. https://www.highcharts.com/support see that. Also I edited your post to include their tag...

Comment: Can you please show which specific scripts are loaded on this page and in which order? It would also help to know any more details about what the script error is. It's possible there is a dependency that is causing the error (for example, the Highcharts script is expecting another library to be loaded first).

Comment: Could you open your browser developer console and tell me there are some errors?