# Cannot navigate to facebook.com from WebBrowser Tool in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I tried to navigate to www.google.com and it worked, I even tried to navigate to www.yahoo.com and it still worked!
But when I tried to navigate to www.facebook.com  it doesn't show anything.
Here's the code:

```
 Public Class Simple
    Private Sub Simple_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("https:\\www.facebook.com")
    End Sub
End Class
```

The above code worked well but when I changed the parameter with "https:\www.facebook.com" it didn't work.
I don't know what is causing this?
Maybe it can't load javascript or something (just a guess)

Output when WebBrowser1.Navigate("https:\www.google.com")

[image: Shows the correct output]

Output when WebBrowser1.Navigate("https:\www.google.com")
[image: It just shows the blank screen!]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webpage works in IE, Chrome and Firefox, but not when using the .NET WebBrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42367088)

Comment: The `WebBrowser` control by default uses the IE 7 rendering engine, which is extremely outdated today. Check my answer above to see how change it to IE 11.

Answer (score 1):

WebBrowser is outdated which can cause issue with javascript and other newer libraries. I have just started to used GeckoFx which uses Firefox and not dependent on IE. Use Nuget Console "Install-Package Geckofx45 -Version 45.0.34"

Here's an example how to browse Facebook via GeckoFX

```
Private geckoWebBrowser As Gecko.GeckoWebBrowser

Private Sub WebView_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    InitializeBrowser()        
End Sub

Private Sub InitializeBrowser()
    Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize("Firefox")
    geckoWebBrowser = New Gecko.GeckoWebBrowser()
    geckoWebBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    Me.Controls.Add(geckoWebBrowser)

    geckoWebBrowser.Navigate("https://www.facebook.com")
End Sub
```

Comment: Now the problem is it doesn't show any output window open? It runs the program, the process is started but the output window is not visible to the user! Looks like only adding the code didn't work out well, as I thought it would!

Comment: Can you post your code? I just started using GeckoFX today to automate login via POST and I'm able to view the browser and see any website when I navigate.