# Can you display a mobile webpage in VB.net webbrowser control

Tags: vb.net

I want to be able to display only mobile versions of a webpage in the VB.Net WebBrowser but cant find a way to do it.  In Internet explorer you simply press f12 and from the emulation tab you can change browser profile to windows phone.

As the VB.Net Browser emulates IE I cant see any reason why there isn't a setting to set the browser profile.  I have already changed the registry settings for Browser Emulation to replicate IE 11 but cannot see where you would set Browser Profile.

There doesn't seem to be much out there on this so appreciate it if anyone has any ideas

Comment: It depends how the website you're visiting is configured. Some might try and use the user-agent string to determine whether to display a mobile view. Others might just use the size of the viewport and responsive design techniques to alter the layout.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I ended up using the code below and it seems to do what I need so far.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code I ended up using, seems to display the website correctly in the web browser control.  One additional thing you do need to do is set your Browser emulation in the registry to 11001 for your .exe file or you will see lots of script errors (`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION`)

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1

    <DllImport("urlmon.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)>
    Private Shared Function UrlMkSetSessionOption(ByVal dwOption As Integer, ByVal pBuffer As String, ByVal dwBufferLength As Integer, ByVal dwReserved As Integer) As Integer
    End Function

    Const URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT As Integer = &H10000001

    Public Function ChangeUserAgent(ByVal Agent As String)
        UrlMkSetSessionOption(URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT, Agent, Agent.Length, 0)
    End Function

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim UA As String = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows Phone 8.0; Trident/6.0; IEMobile/10.0; ARM; Touch; Microsoft; Lumia 950)"

        ChangeUserAgent(UA)

        WebBrowser1.Navigate("www.amazon.co.uk", "_self", Nothing, "User-Agent: " & UA)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: If you would like to change the browser emulation programmatically as well I've got a class for that in an [earlier answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42367088/3740093).